# Open a resource along a path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, eclipse-plugin

Is there a shortcut/option to open a resource along a path?

I have a file maincontent.jsp in around 100+ paths in my workspace.
When i do a resource search (`ctrl+shift+r`), i get a listing for all of them.

Now if know the correct path for the resource, can i have that filtered down using some way?

Like if i am having 2 files
*/content/artic/media/main.jsp*
*/content/tropic/media/main.jsp*

Is there a way to filter search to just the second one? A plugin maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can do it with eclipse 3+ version .Check out more about the added patch here [Search with pattern](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=86973).

you can now search for ,

```
     /project_name/some_folder/*/foo.java 
     or
     */some_folder/*/foo.java 
     or just foo.java
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply start typing a full path in the "Open Resource" window (Ctrl-Shift-R).

It must be an absolute path, starting at the workspace root and including the project name.